# Linked List behaving differently

Tags: c

this is my first time asking here.

I was practicing linked list in C and I cannot figure out why my functions behave differently.

I make a linked list of ints 1-10 and delete the even numbers using `delEven()` function.

`delEven()` plays with the node `P`, `P=*node`, to make the changes, which work properly.

However, when I use the `P=*node` to delete all elements in the list in `delAll2`, the list is untouched. When I ran `printList(P)` within the function `delAll2`, the list is properly deleted.

When I use the input `*node` instead of `P` to delete all elements in `delAll`, it is working properly.

I would like to understand why I was able to delete even elements in `delEven` using `P=*node`, when I was not in `delAll2`.

Thanks,

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int dat;
    struct node* next;
};

void printList (struct node* node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        printf("empty\n");
        return;
    }
    while (node->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%2d",node->dat);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("%2d\n",node->dat);
}
void delEven(struct node** node)    
{
    struct node* P;
    P = *node;
    while (P->next != NULL)
    {
        if (P->next->dat%2==0)
        {
            P->next = P->next->next;
        }
        if(P->next->dat%2==0)
        {
            P->next = P->next->next;
        }
        P=P->next;
    }
}

void delAll(struct node** node)
{
    struct node* P;
    P = *node;
    while ((*node)->next != NULL)
    {
        *node = (*node)->next;
    }
    *node = (*node)->next;
}
void delAll2(struct node** node)
{
    struct node* P;
    P = *node;
    while (P != NULL)
    {
        P = P->next;
    }
}void main()
{
    int i;
    struct node* start;
    struct node* Q;
    struct node* P;
    
    start = NULL;
    for(i=1; i<=10;i++)
    {
        Q=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        Q->dat = i;
        Q->next = start;
        start = Q;
    }
    printList(start);
    printList(start);
    delEven(&start);
    printList(start);
    delAll2(&start);
    printList(start);
}
```

output when delAll2:

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
10 9 7 5 3 1
10 9 7 5 3 1
```

output when delAll:

```
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
10 9 7 5 3 1
empty
```

Comment: Please, do not `malloc` every pointer. You can store a pointer value in as many variables as you like. You do _NOT_ allocate memory if you are then going to reassign the pointer. Doing that leaks memory. You also leak memory in your delete functions. The `delEven` function does not reassign the list head in the case where you are deleting the first element. Your `delAll` function, by contrast, does.

Comment: I think you need to understand that because something appears to "work properly" does not mean that it actually works properly, especially in C. Arguably, printList is the only function you have shown that actually works properly.

Comment: Even `printList` doesn't work "properly", because it terminates the process if the list is empty, instead of just returning. It's unlikely this is the desired behavior.

Comment: Yes, I changed the exit(0); to return; in my new code,

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: So I edited out 'malloc' as suggested, I would like to know how delAll and delAll2 differ. I assume @paddy suggests that '*node=(*node)->next' reassigns the list head but 'P=P->next' does not and hence why they differ? I was initially thinking, delEven and delAll2 should behave the same in changing the pointer to the next element.

Comment: Yes, `P` is a local variable. It does not magically affect the pointer that `node` points to. Here is your program with all the identified issues corrected: https://godbolt.org/z/fM33Eojah

Comment: Thanks @paddy. Well I didn't bother mentioning that I needed the first 10 at the front in my full-er code, but thank you. So, I did come up with using your old_node then free(old_node) method in the not-included delAll3 function, but delAll and delAll2 was what I initially came up with and i was wondering why out of curiosity. Also, is there a reason why const is needed for printList?

Comment: Fine, well if you need the value 10, I would say `delEven` is not a well-behaved function because it doesn't do what it says on the tin. If you always want to delete even values after the head node, then pass it a pointer to the head's `next` member. The `const` is not strictly necessary, but is a courtesy to indicate the function does not modify the list, and also a safety because it _cannot_ modify the list unless you take extra steps to force it. Anyway I hope you learned something. Happy coding!

Comment: None of the delete functions actually deletes any of the allocated nodes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I noticed that it doesn't 'delete' the memory but simply changes the pointer to the element after, however, this is from a lecture example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When managing linked lists, you should avoid having multiple versions of code to do the same thing in multiple locations.

Make a *single* function to delete a node. I recommend one that looks like this:

```
void deleteNextNode(struct node **list, struct node *node_before);
// node_before is the node _before_ the node to delete
// node_before == NULL to delete the first node in the list
// *list is updated if necessary
```

Once you have that, you can rewrite your `delEven()` as:

```
void delEven(struct node **list)
{
  // Delete all even-valued nodes at the head of the list
  while (*list && isEven(list->dat))
    deleteNextNode(list, NULL);
  if (!*list) return;  // (it might have been the whole list)

  // Find and delete even-valued nodes in the rest of the list
  struct node *before = *list;  // (list might be a single node at this point)
  while (before->next)

    // if the next node is even, delete it
    if (isEven(before->next->dat))
      deleteNextNode(list, before);

    // else advance to the next “before” node
    else
      before = before->next;
}
```

Notice how we had to handle the (head of list) and (rest of list) cases separately?